# Cache NSData(with UIImages)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, multithreading, uitableview, uiimageview

Currently, I'm working on the client for the website. I have tonne of images that I need to load to my TableView. Here is what I'm currectly doing:

```
NSDictionary *propertyItems = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.fio.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0f];

    if([propertyItems objectForKey:@"online"] == [NSNumber numberWithInt:1])
        cell.fio.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.6 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

    dispatch_queue_t downloadPhotosQueue = dispatch_queue_create("downloadPhotosQeue", NULL);
    dispatch_async(downloadPhotosQueue, ^{
        NSData *photosData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/%@", [propertyItems objectForKey:@"photo_trumb"]]]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.pic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:photosData];
        });

    });

    cell.fio.text = [propertyItems objectForKey:@"fio"];
```

I'm doing this in **cellForRowAtIndexPath:** method.
Everything is loading fast. But the problem is, when I'm scrolling my table down, and after again up, the images are reloading over and over again.

**Question:** Is there any way to easily cache my UIImages that I'm getting from the server? So if they are loaded once, they wouldn't reload over and over again, while I'm running the app. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView/). I use it and it works like a charm. Just set the image url and it handles everything itself.

```
AsyncImageView *imageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc]init];
imageView.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.es/logos/classicplus.png"];
```

It caches the image in memory so it won't retrieve it from the server again. It will also release them when receiving a memory warning.

Answer (score 1):

To load image from a website I use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). It provides a class to load an image from an URL:

> Start by adding #import "UIImageView+AFNetworking" to the top of a
>   controller or a view implementation file. This category adds methods
>   to UIImageView, like:
>
> [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"…"]];

Answer (score 1):

i recommend [this](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/) library to accomplish what you want.

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithString:@"www.yourimagepath.path"]]
      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image.jpg"]];
```

the library will cache the image for you. you can also set the setHolder of the image, so it wont look like a blank image while the images are downloading.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here :

```
NSData *photosData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/%@", [propertyItems objectForKey:@"photo_trumb"]]]];
```

**dataWithContentsOfURL**

It launch a request to the Url everytime the function is called (everytime you scrolled).
You need to load all the picture before cellForRowAtIndexPath.
Like in ViewDidLoad.
You can just store them in an array and display your picture's array in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

If it's really fast to load like you say : jsut load picture Once in CellForRowAtIndexPath. Store them in a mutableArray. And check if the picture already exist .